# How to cancel installation of Matlab while applying changes?

Tags: software-center, matlab, software-installation

Out of curiosity to try *Matlab* I mistakenly installed the *Matlab* from the Ubuntu Software Center.

I did not realize that it was just an upgrade for the installed program. Now it wants the directory where the *Matlab* is installed. As I do not have *Matlab* installed now I can't give the directory.

So, now I want to remove it from the progress tab but there is no X (i.e., cancel) button, and as it was not completed I can't shop for any further software from Ubuntu Software Center.

What can I do?

Comment: have you tried `alt+f4` it?

Answer (score 3):

Close Software Center.

Open a Terminal window do one of the following:

1. If you had installed "MATLAB" from the Software Center, type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove --purge matlab-support
   ```
2. If you had installed "FreeMat" from the Software Center, the command is similar:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove --purge freemat
   ```